# NullReference when porting C code to unsafe C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to implement Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm in C# similar to the implementation in pure C.

Don't tell me about Regex and being free from work with memory in C#, please.
Because , the aim of this topic is not the true and useful of C# features, but about the work with pointers exactly in C# and also about memory work with learning exactly such features.

Let me show you implementations both in C# and pure C.

C# http://ideone.com/Ck0G0

Pure C http://ideone.com/FVAzU

I have no problems with the version in Pure C, it works well with no problem, but not with C# version.

I have problems in C# on this line:

```
    int*[] d = new int*[M * sizeof(int)];
    *d[0] = 0;
```

I'm catching **NullReferenceException was handled** with setting 0 value to *d[0].

I have read this reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx

*The exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to dereference a null object reference.*

I don't understand at all why this stuff is null in my C# code?

I have define *d pointer to int[] array and have allocated memory for this with the new[] operator, so why does it tell me, that I'm dereferencing a null object reference if the memory was already allocated?

Also there is a question about explicitly deleting pointers in C#.

I know, that it could be done with *fixed*, but if I want this without using this keyword?

As I remember , I must call Dispose() method for this ( but for *d I haven't found this method ), set to null and call GC.Collect(). Is this way the right method?

Thanks,

Best Regards!

Comment: What exactly is the point of this exercise?

Comment: Please don't spam this in every damn chat room.. its considered spamming and certainly won't encourage people to help you.

Comment: @bryan-crosby manual work with memory in C# ( I want to delete object in functions when I want it, but not when GC will do it ), working with pointer and type in C#

Comment: Your code creates an array of pointers, whose members C# initializes to 0. You then access and dereference one of these members, and get the expected exception. This could would have problems in C as well.  C wouldn't initialize your array of pointers, and you'd dereference a garbage address and likely get a memory access exception.

Comment: In fact, it's quite likely to lead to a boatload of people downvoting you and bitching to a moderator about you.

Comment: @DeadMG I don't care about downvoting, I live in real life and here I'm getting best answers on which I'm very thankful. If I get -1 millions votes I wont'be disapointed.

Comment: @walkingTarget in C all works well, you could try the pure C code. It works well. As I know I you malloc() some memory , it would be with some default values, so if memory was allocated you may to assign any value and there would not be any error, no?

Comment: @user167908 - My point is to get you thinking about your code here.  It wouldn't work in either language.  Consider how to correct it.

Comment: @user167908: You're on the wrong track. Please try to learn at least the very basics of C# before you attempt to port C code to unsafe C#.

Comment: @dtb what bases? about System.Object ierarchy , that all types are inhereted from it, about boxing, jit, layer abstactions? The base of C# isn't connected and with understanding /unsafe code. For sample, you could calling exported functions vi calculating addresses of functions and tring to insert __asm code in C# all theses could be, but basis of CLR or C# ( but why C#, I shall leran only semantics, all type are not language stuff , its stuff of .NET VM ) - base of .NET won't help you to work well with /unsafe as work with Native API in Windows (non Win32 layer )

Comment: @walkingTarget You have said, that it wouldn't work, but on C/C++ it works well you could try it both on ideone and yourself. It works!!! Here: http://ideone.com/jCfXl and look at the result info 
result: Success    time: 0.01s    memory: 2856 kB     returned value: 0 

input: no

output:It begins on: 6

Comment: @walkingTarget cause some C/C++ native compilers as MS are setting values to 0xccccccc or 0xfffffff when you allocating memory by default as other popular as I remember

Comment: @user167908 - I don't know how you don't get this.  Your ported C# code creates a very different array.  In C you're creating an array of ints and point d to the first element.  In C# you're creating an array of int pointers, then you try to access the first uninitialized member and dereference it.  I fear you have a poor grasp on pointers, and this is what you should address *first*!

Comment: @walkingTarget there is important to admit, that only the semantics of C# and C are likely but not equal, as I understand it's also with the pointer in C# here.

Comment: @walkingTarget you just said, that in any language it won't work, I just have corrected you about C code, that it works pretty fine as you see.

Comment: You should care about downvotes if you want to continue asking questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/46642

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Indeed: _`This account is temporarily suspended because of low-quality contributions. The suspension period ends in 7 days.`_ I'm sure the OP is disappoint. Shame, this seems like an interesting question, despite lack of experience of the asker

Answer (score 5):

`int *d = (int*)malloc(M * sizeof(int));` allocates memory for `M` `int` values. `d` points to the allocated memory. So it's not an array of pointers, but a pointer to an array.

In C#, you can create an array of `M` `int` values and store a reference to the array in a variable as follows:

```
int[] d = new int[M];
d[0] = 0;
```

The array is a managed object; you don't need to manually free it, dispose it or invoke the garbage collector.

The NullReferenceException  you see in your code is caused by your attempt to dereference the pointer in `d[0]`, which is initialized to `null` by the array creation expression.

Comment: more corrent int[] d = new int[M * sizeof(int)], no? But if I want to allocate memory in C# through pointers like in C, is there any way to do the same?

As for C I know that I'm allocating memory in size of M * sizeof(int), type casting to int* and setting to int *d pointer for using all allocated memeory.

Comment: the Object.Array is managed of course, but what is managed in C#, not only the another layer on unmanaged stuff, which also could be controlled?

Comment: No. I wrote `int[] d = new int[M];` and I meant it.

Comment: Ahh... See, in C# int*[] is strongly array of pointers, but not the pointer to int[] array...

Comment: But doesn't here any way to set the reference between single pointer with the array of some base type as int or char in C#? Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you try to understand C# without `unsafe` code before you start writing unsafe code. You cannot simply take C code and assume it will work without modification in C# if you slap `unsafe` around it.

Comment: I have tried to write without /unsafe and have work with C# on Silverlight and simple apps wihtout using unsafe stuff and I don't like it. Cause it reminds me the ready-toy, which frees you from pure understand what really proceses in you clr-program.

I suggest the better way is to learn ILASM/unsafe and .net vm architecture.

Comment: @user167908 at least this last point of yours is worth voting up!! Btw why u people dont have a real name rather than some cryptic code as user name??

Comment: @mawia because they tend to get account suspension and make another account as has already happened to his account (suspended).